# How can I take 120 fps video on iPhone 5s without slow-mo?

Tags: camera, iphone

How can I take 120 fps videos by iPhone 5S without using slow motion feature ?

Comment: Slow motion is the one that does the 120 frames per second. So why not using it if you want the 120 fps?

Comment: because I just want 120 fps video that is not slow motion.

Comment: I think we are confusing something. Recording at high speed and playing at lower speed creates the slow motion effect, while playback at same speed (120fps) plays at normal speed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Slow motion" is a application name for recording at 120 frames per second.

Recording at 120 fps requires that software feature enabled.

Playback speed is your choice, slow motion or not.

Answer (score 1):

Shooting at "slow motion" is shooting 120 frames per second realtime. If you playback the resulting video at 120fps, you will see it in realtime. The "Slow motion" is a post-recording playback feature that slows the 120fps video down to 30fps. So recording "slow motion" is indeed giving you true 120fps video.

Answer (score 0):

You can first take videos with the slow motion feature then edit the video.Just scroll the blue line towards the another blue line then it will be just a normal video and not a slow motion video.